# in C#/Powershell - Is it possible to change the Idle TimeOut for an IIS Application Pool?

Tags: c#, iis, powershell

I want to disable the idle timeout (Set it to Zero) of an application pool and I want to perform this at setup time, is it possible to perform this action from C# or PowerShell?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are using PowerShell 2 or later, you should have access to [Set-ItemProperty](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849844.aspx).  You'll also want to load the [WebAdministration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx) module.

You can then do (example taken from [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1167786.aspx/1))

```
Set-ItemProperty ("IIS:\AppPools\$name") -Name processModel.idleTimeout -value ( [TimeSpan]::FromMinutes(0))
```

and verify that the value was changed with

```
Get-ItemProperty ("IIS:\AppPools\$name") -Name processModel.idleTimeout.value
```

Comment: This answer didn't work for me. I've added a version that works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41111237/260303

Comment: Works great for me but you need to make sure "WebAdministration" is installed and loaded, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24393229/2912011) useful in getting this to work.

Comment: It worked for me as follows:

$ts = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 0
Set-ItemProperty ("IIS:\AppPools\$name") -Name processModel.idleTimeout -Value $ts

Answer (score 7):

@R0MANARMY's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811427/in-c-powershell-is-it-possible-to-change-iis-idle-time-out-from-application-p/18216465#18216465) (currently the most popular) didn't work for me. It runs fine, but the subsequent check shows that the idle timeout is unchanged.

Based on [this blog post](http://d.evops.co/?p=150), that answer modifies an in-memory copy of the object. I modified the sample code in [R0MANARMY's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811427/in-c-powershell-is-it-possible-to-change-iis-idle-time-out-from-application-p/18216465#18216465) as:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools\$name | ForEach { $_.processModel.IdleTimeout = [TimeSpan]::FromMinutes(0); $_ | Set-Item; }
```

Comment: A one liner that works. Don't forget to start with Import-Module WebAdministration though.

Answer (score 4):

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools
   -applicationPoolDefaults.processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use the `ServerManager Class` in your code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.aspx

Comment: I was doing a quick proof of concept for both solutions you provided, but they don't seem to work on Window Server 2003 as ServerManager works on iis 7 and appcmd only exist on more recent versions of IIS

Answer (score 1):

I use the following function to generically grab an app pool object:

```
$query = "Select * From IIsApplicationPoolSetting WHERE WAMUserName LIKE '%$uServer'"
$query
$pools = Get-WmiObject -Authentication 6 -ComputerName $server -Query $query -Namespace 'root/microsoftiisv2' 
if ($pools)
{
    foreach ($pool in $pools)
    {
        Write-Host("    WAM Pool: " + $pool.Name + ", " + $pool.WAMUserName + " (" + $pool.WAMUserPass + ")")
    }
}
```

And from an unrelated piece of code, here's where I place a site in a new App Pool. It's just an example how to use Set-WMIInstance.

```
if ($site.AppPoolID -ne $poolID)
{
    # Write-Host("Updating $($site.Name) from $($site.AppPoolID) to $($poolID)")
    $wmiArgs = @{"AppPoolID"=$poolID}

    [void](Set-WMIInstance -InputObject $site -Arguments $wmiArgs)
} else {
    # Write-Host("No update needed")
}
```

Use Get-Member to learn what properties your $pool has, then use Set-WMIInstance to modify them.

Comment: Note that this approach only works if you have the IIS 6 WMI Compatibility feature installed.

Answer (score 1):

When using powershell use the following:

```
$appPoolName = "xxxAppPool"
&"$env:windir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd" set APPPOOL $appPoolName /processModel.idleTimeout:0.00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete Powershell sample showing how to create an application pool (for ASP.NET Core) and set many of its values:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$appPoolName     = "MyWebPool"
$appPoolFullName = "IIS:\AppPools\$appPoolName"

if(!(Test-Path $appPoolFullName)) {
    New-WebAppPool $appPoolName -Force

    Set-ItemProperty $appPoolFullName -Name managedPipelineMode -Value Integrated
    Set-ItemProperty $appPoolFullName -Name managedRuntimeVersion -Value "" # means "No Managed Code"
    Set-ItemProperty $appPoolFullName -Name startMode -Value AlwaysRunning

    $3_days = New-TimeSpan -Days 3
    Set-ItemProperty $appPoolFullName -Name processModel.idleTimeout -Value $3_days
    Set-ItemProperty $appPoolFullName -Name processModel.identityType -Value NetworkService
    Set-ItemProperty $appPoolFullName -Name processModel.idleTimeoutAction -Value Suspend

    $zero_ts = New-TimeSpan
    Set-ItemProperty $appPoolFullName -Name recycling.periodicRestart.time -Value $zero_ts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the script that i decided to use:

```
$myApplicationPool = Get-WmiObject -Class IISApplicationPoolSetting -Namespace "root\microsoftiisv2" | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'W3SVC/APPPOOLS/DefaultAppPool'}
$myApplicationPool.IdleTimeout=0
$myApplicationPool.Put()
```

If someone else has a better approach for this please let me know.

Hope this help someone

Regards.

Comment: Note that this approach only works if you have the IIS 6 WMI Compatibility feature installed.

Answer (score 0):

Get Application Pool Configuration (For Reference)

```
$appPoolName = 'MyAppPoolName'
$appPoolPath = '/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/Add[@name="' + $appPoolName + '"]//.'
Get-WebConfiguration $appPoolPath -PSPATH iis:
```

Set Application Pool Idle Timeout

```
$appPoolName = 'MyAppPoolName'
$appPoolPath = '/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/Add[@name="' + $appPoolName + '"]/processModel'
Set-WebConfigurationProperty $appPoolPath -Name idleTimeout -value ([TimeSpan]::FromMinutes(0)) -PSPATH iis:
```

Comment: -Name idleTimeout gives me an error (Propert idleTimeout is not found on <APP POOL NAME>). The right name is processModel.idleTimeout.