# Quartz.NET Scheduler AppDomain

Tags: quartz.net

I have a web application and have setup Quartz to initialize the scheuduler during application starts up. My question is does Quartz Scheduler live within the same appdomain or the scheduler has its own appdomain?

The reason I asked this is because in my Quartz job, I need to retrieve some configuration data using ConfigurationManager.GetSection["MySettings"] (which is available in my web.config) and sometimes it will complain that it can't find the configuration.

What I'm puzzled is this does not happen to all the instances of the job, it is intermitent.

Anyone faces this kind of issue before?

Regards,
lyf

Comment: have you ever considered to close or comment one answer?

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do is to use [JobDataMap](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_3.html).

Answer (score 0):

It runs on the same AppPool, but on different threads,  I have my Quartz.NET hosted on a Singleton WCF Service, and the only thing that i had to modify was the Application Pool IdleTimeout, if you don't change that you are at risk that your application pool will be "Stand-by" when idle, change to Zero (no timeout), you can do it manually or by code as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811427/in-c-powershell-is-it-possible-to-change-iis-idle-time-out-from-application-po)  this post

-Regards